# CLGeocoder in Swift - unable to return string when using reverseGeocodeLocation

Tags: swift, clgeocoder

I'm attempting to use CLGeocoder to return the location of coordinates in a string. My code currently looks like this:

```
func getPlaceName(latitude: Double, longitude: Double) -> String {

let coordinates = CLLocation(latitude: latitude, longitude: longitude)
var answer = ""

CLGeocoder().reverseGeocodeLocation(coordinates, completionHandler: {(placemarks, error) -> Void in
    if (error != nil) {
        println("Reverse geocoder failed with an error" + error.localizedDescription)
answer = ""
    }

    if placemarks.count > 0 {
        let pm = placemarks[0] as CLPlacemark
        answer = displayLocationInfo(pm)
    } else {
        println("Problems with the data received from geocoder.")
answer = ""
    }
})

return answer

}

func displayLocationInfo(placemark: CLPlacemark?) -> String
{
if let containsPlacemark = placemark
{

    let locality = (containsPlacemark.locality != nil) ? containsPlacemark.locality : ""
    let postalCode = (containsPlacemark.postalCode != nil) ? containsPlacemark.postalCode : ""
    let administrativeArea = (containsPlacemark.administrativeArea != nil) ? containsPlacemark.administrativeArea : ""
    let country = (containsPlacemark.country != nil) ? containsPlacemark.country : ""

    println(locality)
    println(postalCode)
    println(administrativeArea)
    println(country)

    return locality

} else {

    return ""

}

}
```

Everything seems to be working, apart from being able to return the string from getPlaceNames(). I only every get the following returned:

```
Optional("")
```

The displayLocationInfo() function seems to work fine, as the println()s come out ok. So I believe that the getPlaceName() function is indeed getting the locality string from displayLocationInfo().

Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: reverseGeocodeLocation is asynchronous. Your return statement will be executed on the main thread before reverseGeocodeLocation finishes.

Comment: Is there an easy way around this? I have tried returning directly from the CLGeocoder(), but it's telling me I can't return a String due to it being Void. I've played around and tried telling it to return a string, but it's obviously not liking that either. Thanks.

Comment: You should set up a completion block for your function getPlaceName and just pass the answer through that block instead of trying to use a return statement

Comment: I posted an example of making a function with a completion block

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since `reverseGeocodeLocation` is an asynchronous function, you need to make your `getPlaceName` function pass the answer back via a block instead of a return statement. Example:

```
func getPlaceName(latitude: Double, longitude: Double, completion: (answer: String?) -> Void) {

   let coordinates = CLLocation(latitude: latitude, longitude: longitude)

   CLGeocoder().reverseGeocodeLocation(coordinates, completionHandler: {(placemarks, error) -> Void in
       if (error != nil) {
           println("Reverse geocoder failed with an error" + error.localizedDescription)
           completion(answer: "")
       } else if placemarks.count > 0 {
           let pm = placemarks[0] as CLPlacemark
           completion(answer: displayLocaitonInfo(pm))
       } else {
           println("Problems with the data received from geocoder.")
           completion(answer: "")
       }
   })

}
```

Comment: Thanks for all the help. I'm stumped on how to call the function. I've taken a look on a few websites (with the one at https://thatthinginswift.com/completion-handlers seeming to be the most beginner-friendly), but I still can't figure out how to add that extra completion argument.

Comment: The closet I've come to working this out so far is it: 'getPlaceName(Double(latitude), Double(longitude), { (answer) -> Void in
            println(answer)
        })'

Comment: Figured it out! Thank you for the help, ad121.

Comment: No problem... glad you figured it out.